Snowpark- How to read contents from a stage file
I am trying to read the content from the stage file using snowpark session api
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session

session = get_active_session()
location = "@mystage/stage/mypath/filename.parquet"
df = session.read.parquet(location)

df.show()

this return empty record with column name.
i checked the file in the path and found file is present in the stage path
I tried different way to get the file content from the file nothing seems working.
